# how to Optimize SQL query cross apply

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to optimize this SQL statement. I have tried to put code written in cross apply in another function and in select.

```
SELECT i1.hprop AS investorid, i2.hprop AS investmentid, RATE.dRate
FROM intprop i1
INNER JOIN property p1
    ON p1.hmy = i1.hprop
INNER JOIN [owner] o1
    ON o1.hmyperson = p1.hlegalentity
CROSS JOIN intprop i2
INNER JOIN CUREXCHRATETYPE c
    ON c.hmy = o1.hexchangeratetype
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT dRate
    FROM (
        SELECT dRate, dtdate, max(DTDATE) OVER () mxdate
        FROM intExchangeRate ix
        WHERE ix.HCXRTIDX = o1.hexchangeratetype
            AND ix.HFROMCUR = i2.hcurrency
            AND ix.HTOCUR = i1.hcurrency
            AND dtdate <= convert(DATETIME, N'10/31/2019', 101)
        ) A
    WHERE dtdate = mxdate
    ) RATE
WHERE i1.hprop IN (11648, 11659, 11662, 11668, 11815, 11816, 11817, 11819, 11821, 11823, 11824, 11826, 11828, 11833, 11834, 11835, 11837, 11840, 11842, 11844, 11846, 11848, 11850, 11852, 11854, 11856, 11858, 11860, 11862, 11864, 11866, 11928, 12016, 12026)
    AND i2.hprop IN (
        11649, 11650, 11651, 11652, 11653, 11654, 11655, 11656, 11657, 11692, 11693, 11708, 11709, 11710, 11711, 11712, 11713, 11714, 11715, 11716, 11717, 11718, 11739, 11876, 11877, 11878, 11887, 11660, 11719, 11720, 11721, 11742, 11880, 11881, 11892, 11893, 11663, 11664, 11665, 11666
        )
```

Comment: It may be useful to note what specifically you’re trying to optimize. Is the query running particularly slow? Is there a performance threshold you’re aiming for? Or are you just looking for tips to improve the query in general? It may be useful to include the execution plan as well.

Comment: The query is running for 10 min for 10000 records. I am trying to optimize the cross apply part in the query.

Comment: What’s the execution plan look like? This does look like a knotty query, and the cross apply certainly attracts the most attention. But it’d be useful to confirm what specific operations are taking up the most processing time. That’s almost always the first step in optimizing a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written, I would recommend an index on:

```
intExchangeRate(HCXRTIDX, HFROMCUR, HTOCUR, dtdate, drate)
```

That said, it might be possible to rewrite the query so it is more efficient.  However, this question does not provide enough information to make suggestions.